# sourceanalyzer is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, maven, cmd, fortify

These are the steps i'm following to set up Fortify SCA for my Source code.

1. Included sca-maven-plugin-3.90.jar as part of my maven plugin (pom.xml).
2. While trying to run `mvn sca:translate .`, it gives me below error.

   ```
   [INFO] Created output dir <dir>
   [INFO] cmd: "sourceanalyzer @<dir>/sca-translate-java.txt"
   'sourceanalyzer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   [ERROR] Error invoking sourceanalyzer. Exit code: 1.
   Verify your project settings and your SCA installation.
   [INFO] Executing command: sourceanalyzer -b <id> -group-id -artifact-id <artifact> -show-module
   ERROR] Command execution failed. Exit code: 1. Make sure that the executable is available
   ```

Not sure what i'm missing here.

Comment: Is the Fortify bin directory in your path?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can run sourceanalyzer directly from the command line.

```
C:\>sourceanalyzer -?
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to reinstall Fortify but first check your PATH variable.

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
```

That should report the Fortify install location bin directory:

```
C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_$version\bin
```